# How to make horizontal CSS3 menu like this

Tags: css, menu

How can I make a CSS3 menu like the menu placed in below website?

http://www.bardia-textile.com/en/

I mean top menu that has fancy effect. please at least tell me the name of these kinds of menus in the way I could find some more examples.

Comment: this is a flash object, its not made with css. it is very easy though to achieve this effect, just try implementing it and if you encounter any issue post here and we will help you out

Comment: That seems to be done using Flash. Similar effect can be achieved with CSS3 but how to do it from scratch is too broad a question. You would have use `transform`, pseudo-elements, some absolute positioning etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an awesome solution for you. It looks like the site's one but i tried some other colors.
Take a look,its awesome and very simple, [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/4ww8bca1/):

How it looks like? here...

[image: eawesome menu]

Implementation:

Html

```
<div id="main">    
<ul id="navigationMenu">    
    <li>
        <a class="rotate home" href="#">
            <span>home</span>
        </a>
    </li>        
    <li>
         <a class="rotate about" href="#">
            <span>About</span>
         </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="rotate services" href="#">
            <span>Services</span>
        </a>
    </li>        
    <li>
        <a class="rotate contact" href="#">
            <span>Contact</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#666;
    background:#111 no-repeat;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navigationMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:2px;
    width:15px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;

}

#navigationMenu ul{
    list-style:none;
}

#navigationMenu span{
    /* Container properties */
    width:0;
    left:38px;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;

    /* Text properties */
    font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0.6px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:39px;

    /* CSS3 Transition: */
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;

    /* Future proofing (these do not work yet): */
    -moz-transition: 0.25s;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

#navigationMenu a{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

/* General hover styles */
#navigationMenu a:hover span{ width:20px; padding-left:15px;overflow:visible; }
#navigationMenu a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;   
    /*CSS outer glow with the box-shadow property
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;*/
}

/* Blue Button */
#navigationMenu .home span{
    background-color:#1e8bb4;
    color:#223a44;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #44a8d0;
}

/* Orange Button */
#navigationMenu .about span{
    background-color:#c86c1f;
    color:#5a3517;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

/* Yellow Button */
#navigationMenu .services span{
    background-color:#d0a525;
    color:#604e18;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}


/* Purple Button */
#navigationMenu .contact span{
    background-color:#af1e83;
    color:#460f35;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d244a6;
}

/* The styles below are only needed for the demo page */
#main{
    margin:80px auto;
    position:relative;
    width:240px;
}

a, a:visited,a:active {
    color:#0196e3;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a img{
    border:none;
}

.rotate {
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Of course,it is so simple so you can adjust this one to your needs.
Hope you like that!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.sub').click(function(){
        $('.sub').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
#menu{
 position:absolute;
 width:210px;
 height:auto;
 background:transparent;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 left:100px;
 top:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.sub{
 display:block;
 padding: 16px 0;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:10;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.sub:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 background:gray;
 display:block;
 width:200px;
 height:50px;
 margin-top: -34px;
 z-index:-2;
 right:-10px;
}
.sub:before{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 background:red;
 display:block;
 width:210px;
 height:50px;
 margin-top: -16px;
 z-index: -1;
 right:-220px;
 -webkit-transition:right .3s;
}
.sub:hover:before{
 right:0px;
}
.active:after{
 right:0px;
 width:210px;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="sub active">subs1</div>
    <div class="sub">subs2</div>
    <div class="sub">subs3</div>
    <div class="sub">subs4</div>
    <div class="sub">subs5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like previously said this is a flash object but you can do something similar using CSS and jquery rotate function [this is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/h0fcp4v3/) you can remove  `display: inline;`   to obtain an horizantal list.

#### EDIT:

Horizontally: [see Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h0fcp4v3/3/)